# Htaccess - Rewrite and Redirect url for Kuenan Forum in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that got an feed that shows all new forum posts. When doing this it will show url/#postID

I want to redirect all this links to the correct url without the postID to get the onsite SEO optimal

Exampel

www.mysite.com/forum/category/the-post-titel/#48394 -> ..../the-post-titel/

What would the correct line in htaccess be to redirect all url's with the "/#43244" to just "/"

Comment: Google only notices it if it is a hashbang (`#!`). If it detects a hashbang in a url its send ?_escaped_fragment=value-after-hashbang. I don't think that it in any way negatively affects your ranking, hashbang, or normal hash. Not sure where you get your SEO advice from.

Comment: @Gerben Agreed - the # should not matter for SEO purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this via .htaccess as the `#` or [URL Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not transmitted to the server so .htaccess cannot act on it.

If you are doing this for SEO purposes, the best (and perhaps only) way is to remove this from the feed itself, before people or Search Engines get to it.